# limit ordinal well-founded

Tags: ordinals, well-orders

An ordinal is defined as a woset $(X, ≤)$ such that $X_a
= a$ for all $a ∈ X$.

How can we prove that a limit ordinal is still well-founded? I don't see why there could not be an infinite descending chain of the inclusion or subset relation in a limit ordinal. For example $\omega$ or any other limit ordinal.

Thanks.

Comment: What does $X_a$ denote? More importantly (since it should basically hand you the answer), what is your definition of woset?

Comment: Given a woset (X, ≤) and an element a ∈ X, the segment of X
determined by a is the set
$X_a
= \{x ∈ X|x < a\}$
of all the predecessors of a.

Comment: I got it the first time, thanks. How about your definition of woset?

Comment: But that actually doesn't matter to my question. I'm just wondering how to prove that a limit ordinal is well-founded.

Comment: Ok thanks. A woset is a poset that is total and its strict relation is well-ordered. A poset is a set together with a parial order, which is a relation that is reflexive, anti-symmetric, and transitive. A poset is total if all of its elements are 'comparable'. Finally, it is well-ordered if every nonempty subset has a minimal element, which is equivalent to the fact that there is no infinitely descending chain. E.g. no chain such that $x_0 > x_2 > x_3 > \ldots$.

Comment: Most likely the definition of ordinals does indeed matter, since well-foundedness will be proved using the definition and transfinite induction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal and $\alpha>\beta_1>\beta_2>\beta_3>...$ is a descending sequence in $\alpha$. Then think about the first term of this sequence, $\beta_1$. Since everything below $\alpha$ is an ordinal (since $\alpha$ is an ordinal), $\beta_1$ is itself an ordinal. But then $\beta_2>\beta_3>\beta_4>...$ is a descending sequence through $\beta_1$!

What this really shows is that *any set of ordinals* is well-ordered by $\in$.

---

You mention the subset relation in the context of ordinals. *This is the wrong relation to have in mind*! There are indeed descending *subset* sequences in $\omega$: e.g. $$\omega\supset (\omega\setminus 1)\supset(\omega\setminus 2)\supset(\omega\setminus 3)\supset . . .$$ But note that the sets in this sequence *aren't ordinals* - in particular, they're not elements of $\omega$!

Comment: +1: I hadn't even considered that possible source of misunderstanding!

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested in the comments above, this is true for *any* woset--ordinal or otherwise.

Suppose that $\langle X,<\rangle$ is a woset, and that $\langle a_n\rangle_{n=0}^\infty$ is a sequence of points of $X$ such that $a_{n+1}\le a_n$ for all $n.$ Now, what can you say about the subset $\{a_n:n\ge0\}$ of $X$? What does that tell you about the sequence?

Comment: Thanks. But what I'm actually wondering is $\textit{why}$ a limit ordinal is a woset in the first place. It is defined as the supremum of all its previous ordinals. How to prove it is a woset.

Comment: Well, take any non-empty subset $A$ of a limit ordinal $X,$ and fix any $a\in A.$ If $a$ is the least element of $A,$ we're done. Otherwise, consider $A\cap X_a.$